# Modeling Regional Quality Based on SUM of GCL / SUM of TAP - Comparing Two Approaches

Tags: machine-learning, estimation, linear-regression, data-analysis

I'm learning Data Science and I'm currently working on analyzing loan data across different regions. My goal is to build a model that can assess the quality of a given region based on the ratio $$\frac{\sum GCL}{\sum TAP},$$ where:

$GCL$ (Gross Credit Loss) = Total Amount Payable - (Issue Value + Bad Debt)

$TAP$ (Total Amount Payable) is the total amount due.

I have two approaches in mind:

1. **Linear Regression Model:**
   Given a set of variables $X_1, ..., X_k$, I can construct a linear regression model predicting the dependent variable $Y = \frac{\sum GCL}{\sum TAP}$. During the model-building phase, I'd select a subset of these variables, resulting in a prediction $Y \sim \sum a_i X_i$. Subsequently, I can segment the regions into quality classes (e.g., A, B, C, D, E) based on the value of $Y$.
2. **Segmentation followed by Modeling**:
   First, I'd arbitrarily create quality classes (e.g., A, B, C, D, E) based on the value of $\frac{\sum GCL}{\sum TAP}$. Given the set of variables $X_1, ..., X_k$, I'd estimate the distribution of a random variable $Z$, indicating the quality class a given region belongs to. Then, I'd define a function $f$ based on the distribution parameters (e.g., mean, median, deviation, skewness, etc.). The choice of $f$ would be determined by e.g. business requirements (it is not crucial now), and the value $f(Z)$ would be the final model output indicating the quality of the region.

**Question:**
If the two models yield different results (e.g., regarding the quality of a given region), is there any analytic way to compare these models and say which one is better?

I'd appreciate any insights or feedback!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Ok, I ask one specified question.